# How to modify a category page using custom template and Custom Layout Update via admin

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, magento

I have a custom template i created to display subcategories within a category.  I would like allow the usage of this template script on a category by category basis by using an xml override in "custom layout update" field.  I do not want to modify the any of the .xml layout files to so as to able to apply this template only on particular categories via the admin.

/theme/template/catalog/category/list.phtml <-- my custom template script

So i am having issues coming up with the xml override to add this template script to content area via the "custom layout update" field in the category admin . This is what i have:

```
 <reference name="content">
 <action method="append">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="collectionlist" template="catalog/category/list.phtml" />
</append>

</reference>
```

All i get is a blank page on the category, and the following error in the apache error log:

```
[Thu Mar 10 00:32:48 2011] [error] [client 72.201.97.195] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in <server_path>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 154
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't need to specify the append method.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="collectionlist" template="catalog/category/list.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is broken. Don't close an `<action>` with an `</append>`.

With this fixed, SimpleXML will be able to parse your layout again.